# Debian/mariadb limit? Nothing helped ! SQLSTATE[HY000] [1135] Can't create a new thread (errno 11 "Resource temporarily unavailable");

Tags: mysql, multithreading, debian, mariadb, limits

I tried to solve this problem for 2 months.
I already increased all limits that I heard of and still nothing.
Problem is that mariadb (previously the same happend with mysql 5.5.x) is having threads limit about 4500-4900 threads at one time.
When my software tries to create more connections and all threads are used i get this error:

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [1135] Can't create a new thread (errno 11 "Resource temporarily unavailable");**

Now, here are configs and limits that i have currently on server.
The server is Debian 9

**Htop number of processes:**
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHfd2.png)

**Mysql connections:**
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 59% (4890/8200)

root:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

```
944163
```

root# cat /proc/$( pgrep -o mysql )/limits

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             472081               472081               processes
Max open files            16364                16364                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       472081               472081               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us


ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 472081
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65536
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 472081
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

cat /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf | grep -v "#"

```
[server]
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size     = 1G
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
thread_stack        = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 4096
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 8200
max_connect_errors     = 10000000
query_cache_limit   = 1G
query_cache_size        = 30G
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow-query.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes
table_open_cache = 65536
open_files_limit = 65536
key_buffer_size = 512M
table_cache = 4096
max_heap_table_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=1G
skip_name_resolve
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

[embedded]
[mariadb]
[mariadb-10.1]
```

cat /etc/security/limits.conf

```
root soft  nofile 65536
root hard  nofile 65536
root soft stack 65536
root hard stack 65536

www-data soft nofile 65536
www-data hard nofile 65536

mysql soft nofile 65536
mysql hard nofile 65536
mysql soft nproc 65536
mysql hard nproc 65536
mysql soft stack 65536
mysql hard stack 65536

nobody soft nofile 65536
nobody hard nofile 65536

*          soft     nproc          40960
*          hard     nproc          40960
*          soft     nofile         40960
*          hard     nofile         40960
* soft stack 65536
* hard stack 65536

# End of file
```

cat /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Disable IPv6 autoconf
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_pinfo = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_pinfo = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.accept_ra_pinfo = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.accept_ra = 0


net.core.somaxconn=1024
#kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 5000000



# Number of times SYNACKs for passive TCP connection.
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

# Allowed local port range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535

# Protect Against TCP Time-Wait
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1

# Decrease the time default value for tcp_fin_timeout connection
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15

# Decrease the time default value for connections to keep alive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15

### TUNING NETWORK PERFORMANCE ###

# Default Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216

# Default Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216

# Increase number of incoming connections
net.core.somaxconn = 4096

# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384

# Increase the tcp-time-wait buckets pool size to prevent simple DOS attacks
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

fs.file-max = 500000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 20480
```

**I found something here:**

```
root@baza:~# systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-10-26 17:02:27 CEST; 1 months 11 days ago
  Process: 12508 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12284 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12106 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment
_WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12102 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12099 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 12244 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
    Tasks: 4915 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─12244 /usr/sbin/mysqld

paź 26 17:02:23 baza systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
paź 26 17:02:24 baza mysqld[12244]: 2017-10-26 17:02:24 140040257753664 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1) starting as process 12244 ...
paź 26 17:02:24 baza mysqld[12244]: 2017-10-26 17:02:24 140040257753664 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16364 (request: 16403)
paź 26 17:02:27 baza systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
```

**Then:**
systemctl show -all | grep Tasks
DefaultTasksAccounting=yes
DefaultTasksMax=4915

---

#### Solved

**Solved by adding those: (stupid default limit of 4915 threads)**
**DefaultTasksMax=infinity to /etc/systemd/system.conf
TasksMax=infinity to /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service**

Comment: How much RAM is on your server?
V8 mysql suggests thread_cache_size=100  CAP vs 4096 you have asked for.
Use of mysqlcalculator.com will help guide you toward reasonable values for the 'per connection' RAM utilization.  Requested values are over the top and will cause you to be OOM.

Comment: There is 29GB used out of 115GB. 32 cores used in 20%.
Setting thread_cache_size to defualt 16 or more to 8000 doesnt change anything.
Mysql just has limit but this limit is like totally different.
The limit is 4800 mysql connections/threads. If that is exceeded then i get this error.

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> show status where `variable_name` LIKE '%thread%';
| Variable_name                            | Value   |
| Threads_cached                           | 2221    |
| Threads_connected                        | 2595    |
| Threads_created                          | 4141324 |
| Threads_running                          | 64      |
SO THIS IS NOT OUT OF MEMORY ISSUE :) and thats the point in all of this

Comment: Found something: systemctl status mysql: Tasks: 4915 (limit: 4915)

Comment: systemctl show -all | grep Tasks
DefaultTasksAccounting=yes
DefaultTasksMax=4915
This is it !!!

Comment: Great, thanks for digging deeper.  Within /etc/sysctl.conf  you will find 
net.core.somaxcon=1024   and then later you will find 
net.core.somaxconn = 4096 

Possibly a leading # on both of these and a new higher limit will get additional capacity for you.

Hoping you will also take advantage of mysqlcalculator.com to get below 5.6 Terrabytes calculated RAM required if all threads were possibly busy.

Comment: Thx , i set net.core.somaxcon to 20k

Answer (score 2):

Once again:
SOLVED by adding those: (stupid default limit of 4915 threads ) DefaultTasksMax=infinity to /etc/systemd/system.conf TasksMax=infinity to /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service

Answer (score 0):

**Threads is not the *real* problem!**

What version of MySQL?  For virtually all versions, `query_cache_size = 30G` is *VERY* bad on performance.  Don't go past about `50M`.

Really bad:  Load avg = 11; Connections = 4890/8200.  Dozens of *active* connections is usually too many -- MySQL stumbles over itself, and no *throughput declines* while latency goes through the roof.

I usually suggest throttling things at the *client*, so as to avoid the thundering hurd inside MySQL.

`Threads_running = 64` -- That confirms my fears above.

`key_buffer_size = 1G` -- If you are not using MyISAM (and you should not be), this is wasting a lot of RAM.  A reasonable size is 40M.

You have the slow log turned on.  What does `pk-query-digest` (or `mysqldumpslow -s t`) say are the worst few queries?

How much RAM?  I see more than 50GB committed -- do you have 115GB?  If not, then the IOPs are in swapping.  This is deadly for performance.

Please provide the settings and status as discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning).  I fear there will be more ugly surprises.

There is probably more.  Please act on some of what I have said, then I will pursue this further.

Comment: The number of active connections is all ok. I have about 150'000 http requests per minute and curently 35'000 queries per second to mariadb database. So 5k constant connections to database is ok :D The avg load 8 / 32 cores is also ok. The 5 TB max mysql memory usage is becasue i changed one parameter to very big value for test. But i forgot which was it :D Anyway i have 40 GBmemory used from total 115 GB. Nothing is swapping.

Comment: At least decrease the query_cache_size.  Purging the cache when a write happens is more costly when the cache is bigger.

Comment: I dont have much slow queries thats why i turned this on for monitoring. Most slow queries are when i am dumping database. Anyway i have like 20MB/s constant write. Count: 1939  Time=1.61s (3118s)  Lock=0.00s (0s) and Count: 449  Time=5.20s (2334s). Anyway i changed sort_buffer_size to 5M and now i have OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 84.9G (73% of installed RAM) . Anyway i dont think i can tune anything more than i had before.

Comment: OK i decreased this.

Answer (score 0):

It was introduced to **systemd** in 2015 and now default limit is 512. Please find below reference link which would be helpful to identify issue.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/9ded9cd14

https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/02/tasksmax-another-setting-that-can-cause-mysql-error-messages/